# Regex to match capture group multiple times within subsection of text document

Tags: c#, regex

I am passing an XML document, as text document, though a regular expression process.

```
<YaddaYaddaPrecedingMarkup>includes (a) and (b) and (c) and (d) and ...

<MyElement>SECTIONBEGINS (a) Item A (b) Item B (c) Item C (d) Item D</MyElement>

<YaddaYaddaFollowingMarkup>includes (a) and (b) and (c) and (d) and ...
```

I want my regular expression to capture the bullet labels '(a)' '(b)' '(c)' '(d)' . ( ..etc...) which appear within 'MyElement', whose text begins with "SECTIONBEGINS".

I need this regular expression to ignore any other instances of (a) ... (b) ... (c) appearing elsewhere within my XML-as-text.

If I use:

```
(\([a-z]\))
```

I match (a), (b), (c) throughout the document.  That expression is too unrestricted.

If I use:

```
>SECTIONBEGINS(?:.*?)(\([a-z]\))(?:.*)<
```

I successfully match only within the correct section but I match only '(a)' (the first hit), and not the (b), (c), (d) of that same section.

And I've tried so many other variations, some of which will select the '(d)' instead but none seem to capture more than one hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant 1: Lookbehind

```
(?<=SECTIONBEGINS[^>]*)\([a-z]\)
```

Variant 2: \G anchor + capturing group

```
(?:SECTIONBEGINS|\G)[^<(]*(\([a-z]\))
```

Comment: Could you please further explain your answer so it is more useful to other users?

Comment: The first variation didn't seem to be in my ballpark.

The second variation, using the "/G, and modifying to use that 'look behind' clause, is very close.  It finds the hits I want but also includes the three bullet labels preceding my target section.

The "/G" definition seems to not only include "prior hits" but also "start of document"... and thus it is picking up a few extra hits. Nevertheless, this is closer than anything else I tried so far.

Comment: You should be able to use variant 2 without modification. The \G captures continuous matches starting with the first group after SECTIONBEGINS
https://regex101.com/r/tlah1T/1

Comment: Hey, you're right.  I was testing with Regex101 too but my example text had a fat finger in it. (my first byte was >, rather than < )  I had to flicker back-n-forth a few dozen between our two efforts see what the heck was happening. .. .now I wonder how many of my OWN efforts bombed for the same reason : - )

Awesome sauce.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the `Match.Group.Captures`:

```
Regex.Match(xml, @">SECTIONBEGINS (?<items>\([a-z]\) .+?)+<")
    .Groups["items"].Captures.Cast<Capture>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
```

Or, if you like to group them into key/value pair:

```
var match = Regex.Match(xml, @">SECTIONBEGINS( (\((?<index>[a-z])\) (?<item>.+?)))+<");
Enumerable.Zip(
    match.Groups["index"].Captures.Cast<Capture>(),
    match.Groups["item"].Captures.Cast<Capture>(),
    Tuple.Create)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1.Value, x => x.Item2.Value)
```

EDIT: If you don't care about the bullet labels, you can extract the items through:

```
Regex.Match(xml, @">SECTIONBEGINS( (\((?<index>[a-z])\) (?<item>.+?)))+<")
    .Groups["item"].Captures.Cast<Capture>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
```

Or, if you want to replace the content in place:

```
Regex.Replace(xml, @">SECTIONBEGINS( (\((?<index>[a-z])\) (?<item>.+?)))+<",
    m => string.Format(">SECTIONBEGINS {0}<", string.Join(" ", m.Groups["item"]
        .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
        .Select((x,i) => string.Format("({0}) {1}",
            (char)(((int)'a')+i),
            x.Value.ToUpper() // TODO: your replace logic here
    ))))
)
```

Comment: As a practical matter, I intend to replace the '(a)' and '(b)' with other content, hopefully using the RegEx.Replace() operation.

If I must first use the Match() operation, and walk my hits to do the replace(s), then I think I would take this approach instead: 

- Execute RegEx to find the broad section of bullets which I need to replace.
- Obtain the section's value, and perform all the string replace operations to prepare a Replace string for the whole section
- Execute RegEx .Replace() to change the original section to my prepared replace string

Yeah?